# How to synchronize setTimeout and mobile.navigate using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm creating a small quiz, mobile app using jQuery Mobile, and I'm displaying a 3 second GIF at certain points. Though, because it is shown many times, I don't want to bother the user each time, and if he/she clicks anywhere on the page it goes to the next page, but I also have set up a setTimeout, which waits for three seconds, meaning of the GIF to display completely and then moves to the next page. As you can see this makes a problem. If I click the GIF, it moves to the next page, and then if I again move to the other page, after three seconds are passed it sends me back to the previous page, due to the setTimeout. I have the following code:

**EDIT :**

```
$(document).on("pagechange", function(event, ui) {
    var clicked = false;
    // Here comes some if-else statements checking which page is currently active
   else if ($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "correctGIF") {
        correct++;
        nextpage = hashtag.concat(page, 'Correct');

    $('#correctGIF').append('<img src="images/Correct1.gif">');
        $('#correctGIF').click(function() {
            clicked = true;
            $.mobile.navigate(nextpage);
            alert("alert from click");
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!clicked) {
                $.mobile.navigate(nextpage);
               alert("alert from timeout");
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

So, I need to somehow synchronize it. If there is a click it should ignore the setTimeout part, and if there is no click it should wait for three seconds for the GIF to finish, meaning should activate the setTimeout part. Also please note that this GIF is displayed many times during the quiz, not just once. Any ideas about this?

Comment: @Floradu88 There seems to be some problem. I explained it below in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#correctGIF').off('click').on('click', function () {
        alert('navigate from click');
        console.log('navigate from click');
        if (!$('#correctGIF').hasClass('clickedImageClass')) {
            $('#correctGIF').addClass('clickedImageClass');
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$('#correctGIF').hasClass('clickedImageClass')) {
            alert('navigate from timeout');
            console.log('navigate from timeout');
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

JsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/e35pn/13/

Comment: I think it should be `if (!clicked)`  (or if I'm wrong just use `if (clicked)`, comparing booleans to true or false is a bit... unnecessary ;)

Comment: Or if you want to avoid global variables, you can set a class on the element and check that.

Comment: @Floradu88 There seems to be some problem for me. For the first correct answer it works fine. But after each correct answer it displays the alert one more time. For example, for 4th correct answer when it displays the GIF if you press on it to move to the next page, it displays the alert 4 times.

Comment: Yes, you should declare the variable in the page defined in "nextpage"

Comment: @Floradu88 I already moved clicked outside the pagechange. Also there are defined some other global variables, like nextpage, etc. Though I didn't get what you mean by "declare the variable in the page defined in "nextpage"".

Comment: Meaning that you need to declare the variable in the page that you are navigating into. Will update my code soon.

Comment: @Floradu88 Okay, I will be waiting for your update. Cause like this I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @Floradu88 Are you sure that it works. Because if you click someimage in the jsfiddle, it shows the alert, and after three seconds it also shows the alert from the timeout. Seems like it executes both of them, same as the original problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55436/discussion-between-floradu88-and-ett).